# move back to View Controller from Navigation Controller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am a beginner in Swift Development and I am stuck at one point. I have a ViewController1(Entry Point), Navigation Controller and ViewController2. ViewController2 contains **[XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)** and is embedded in Navigation Controller.I am able to move from ViewController1 to Navigation controller using below code.

```
let navigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController

let viewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ParentViewController") as! ParentViewController
navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now the problem is I am unable to move back to ViewController1 from Navigation Controller.

Able to Move From **ViewController1 -> NavigationController -> ViewController2**

but unable to move back i.e. **ViewController1 <- NavigationController <- ViewController2**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any one

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: popViewController is not working. It is showing the same VC2 again on click of back. But dismiss did the job. This is little weird.

Comment: what weird is there

Answer (score 1):

In your code delete this line:

```
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And when you want to move back just call:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left out the self in one line so if you updated it to look like this :

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

it should work now...

Comment: and why u r pushing and presenting view controller at the same time

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).